# requiring help condensing Jquery

Tags: jquery

What I am looking to create is an image that changes depending on which thumbnail is clicked below that image.  I have looked online and found many superb looking thumbnail gallery viewers with some great effects, however all I need is "simple".

I have cobbled together a bit of script based on elements I have found online which suit my purpose,

HTML:

```
    <img id="image" src="/largeImage1.jpg"><br>
    <a id="link1" href="/largeImage1.jpg">picture 1</a><br>
    <a id="link2" href="/largeImage2.jpg">picture 2</a><br>
    <a id="link3" href="/largeImage3">picture 3</a>
```

Jquery:

```
    $("#link1").click(function() {
      $("#image").fadeOut(50, function() {
        $("#image").attr("src",$("#link1").attr("href"));
      }).fadeIn(500);
      return false;
    });
    $("#link2").click(function() {
      $("#image").fadeOut(50, function() {
        $("#image").attr("src",$("#link2").attr("href"));
      }).fadeIn(500);
      return false;
    });
    $("#link3").click(function() {
      $("#image").fadeOut(50, function() {
        $("#image").attr("src",$("#link3").attr("href"));
      }).fadeIn(500);
      return false;
    });
```

Ok, this is as far as I have got (text links need changing to thumbnails, and a bit of css needs throwing in - this I am familiar with). Where I am stuck is on the jquery (not a favorite subject) - is there a way, which I'm sure there is, of condensing the repeating jquery down. Eventually, I will have somewhere in the region of 12 thumbnails and although I'm happy to type out the same 6 lines of jquery 12 times (just adjusting the thumbnail link each time), if there is a neater (and shorter) way of achieving this I would be happier.

Many thanks in advance, Wayne

Comment: Please see: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Give your links a class to make selecting them easier. Add the click event to all elements of that class. Use `this` to get the element that was clicked and from there find its source:

```
$('.thumb-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#image").fadeOut(50, function() {
        $("#image").attr("src", src);
    }).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I am looking to achieve (size wise). However, is there a way of linking the displayed image to the <a href... link as opposed to the thumbnail image src - the reason being, I would like a different thumbnail to the image displayed.

Comment: I would use a `data-` attribute. Put the full size image src in an attribute like `data-fullsrc="/LargeImage1.jpg"` and access it like  `$(this).data('fullsrc');`

Comment: Hi Jason, not wanting to upset you with my ignorance... I think this is I think exactly what I am after, however I am coming unstuck on where to place these - the anoying this is I know it's going to be simple but could you give a little more info as to where and how I write these into the code. I have been playing on jsfiddle and cannot figure it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HpmN7/414/ I have assumed that now the data attribute will be used, there is no longer a need for the href tags, subsequently I have altered these to div containers. Many thanks for your help on this.

Comment: See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HpmN7/415/ The src for the image to display is pulled from the `data-fullsrc` attribute.

Comment: Many thanks Jason, this is exactly what I have been trying to create. I managed to get the html right, and made one small error in the jquery causing the original image to fade and reload regardless of which thumbnail was clicked. Easy now I'm looking at it!!! Thanks again.

Comment: Had a small issue when transferring to site in that the original image did not change on any thumbnail click, subsequently I have changed the `data-fullsrc` attribute to `alt` and made respective adjustments with the script. for reference to anyone needing the script, I have updated my original fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/HpmN7/418/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you dont have any other anchor tags on the page

```
$('a').click(function(){
 $("#image").attr("src",$(this).attr("href"));
})
```